# Parse Error [empty string]

Tags: css

I've validated my site css through [css-validator.org](http://css-validator.org) and I'm seeing a problem *Parse Error*. Can someone explain what a *Parse Error* is, and how to resolve it?

[CSS Validate url](http://www.css-validator.org/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.254.181.70%2Fprojects%2Fintrigger%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en)

My css is for `.tSearchbox`

```
    .tSearchbox {
      float: right; 
      width: 194px; 
      height: 34px; 
      border: 1px solid #d5d5d5; 
      border-radius:19px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the official validator (jigsaw.w3.org instead of css-validator.org, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605983/)) it seems to [mostly validate](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.254.181.70%2Fprojects%2Fintrigger).

Comment: Thanks to reply @mb21 here is my css validate url again please check  ----   http://www.css-validator.org/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.254.181.70%2Fprojects%2Fintrigger%2Fcss%2Fmain.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en

Comment: Why is the `.css` you are providing here not the same as the one not being validated ? On the validator your `.css` expands `border-radius` into four parts. It has no impact, but please be exact when asking questions, we need precise informations to help you.